# Ubuntu Touch Welcome Screen Does not display correctly on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch, raspberrypi

I am attempting to install Ubuntu Touch on a Raspberry Pi 4.  I downloaded the image file here: https://ci.ubports.com/job/rootfs/job/rootfs-rpi/  I placed it on an SD card using the GNOME Disks Utility, resizing partitions appropriately.  I insert the SD card into the Pi and power it on.  As the Pi boots, I see several screens the last of which is the Welcome Screen.  However, it displays as white and orange stripes.  Because of this, I am unable to finish the installation.  I have tried everything I can think of to get the Welcome Screen to display correctly.  From getting a new image file to changing displays. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: welcome screen here]

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It looks like it boots up the os and makes it to the first boot landing screen but does not render onto my display correctly

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi port of Ubuntu Touch is merely experimental, still pretty much under development, not really supported, as you can see on the [port status page](https://devices.ubuntu-touch.io/device/rpi/), you shouldn't expect it to be usable.